# Updating Theme Framework Getting privileges Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have just Install New woocommerce theme Mystile Version 1.2.9. while using it i am getting error like:

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\wamp\www\tramawoo\wp-content\themes\mystile\functions\admin-functions.php on line 3193"

On some forum i read that i have to upgrade Mystile Theme Framework to "WooFramework update is available (v5.5.5)". to get rid from this error.

So from Dashboard >> Mystile Theme > Theme Options >> when i click on WooFramework update is available (v5.5.5) i get this message.

"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

I am logged in as ADMIN and also i am on my local-server WAMP.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bug in the theme or in the framework.  It's hard to diagnose from afar.  I would suggest that you manually download the new version and just replace it manually.

Comment: from where i can update it WooFramework update 5.5.5. from where to download and then how to update manually

Comment: thanks i got the solution from here here
 http://www.woothemes.com/2012/04/framework-shortcode-exploit-has-been-fixed/

its solved